# Block an http referrer on the server level

Tags: apache-2.2, security, .htaccess, spam

I am seeing multiple fake http referrers to several sites on my server, which for the most part doesn't bother me, except that they distort visitor stats.

I have filtered the questionable domains out in Google Analytics, and I know it's possible to use .htaccess to block these referers.  Unfortunately, there are too many accounts on this server, so editing 40+ .htaccess files every time there's a new spammy referer is not ideal.

Is there an easy way to do this on the server level?

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` can also be used in server config. Something along the lines of

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(.*\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1 [R=301,L]
```

in your server config should do the trick. For this to work though you have to add this to every VirtualHost you want to apply the global configuration on as by default VirtualHosts don't inherit from the global context.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
```

Comment: I use WHM and cPanel and am not familiar with VirtualHost.  But if that means making this change for every site hosted on the server, then that's the same amount of work as copying and pasting the rule in different .htaccess files, isn't it?

Comment: In Cpanel you can create include files for specific, all or one users domains/VirtualHosts. How that is done is described here https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Modify+Virtualhost+Containers+With+Include+Files